# Desktop is not showing with Desktop Folder

Tags: release-hera, desktop, desktop-environment, show-desktop

I like to see my folders etc. which are in Desktop. On eOS, I had to install the `Desktop Folder` app to do this. I have added that in the start up application list. However when I start my laptop, it initially shows the folders on the Desktop. However once I switch between workspace it is completely gone, even from the primary workspace. If I go to Applications and try to click `Desktop Folder` to run, it does nothing. I am using eOS-5.1.3 HERA on Lenovo X1 Carbon 7th Gen. 
Is there any way around to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try rightclick on the desktop and then "Show Desktop"

Comment: Well, this does not work. However this is probably a known issue with `Desktop Folder`.
See this:  https://github.com/spheras/desktopfolder/issues/296

Comment: yes you are right. I am working on VirtualBox Starter icons and DesktopFolders is also not working stable on my machine